# Extracting common code from existing spring boot services and reusing the code using maven and git submodules

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, microservices, git-submodules

So I work on a bunch of spring boot based microservices. The thing is all those services have the same user verification code, same exception handler advice, same AOP based logging etc. Now what I want to do is to extract this code in a separate repository and use this code with each of the services as their component (and I want to be able to edit this code with the service code I will be adding it into).
Basically, when I build the code of that service, I should be able to build that common code project as well which would be present as a sub-directory in each of the services.
Visually, my current situation is this:

```
   service A (present in its own repo,contains common code)
   pom.xml

   service B (present in its own repo,contains common code)
   pom.xml

  ....etc.
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
   service A
      \-----pom.xml
       \----src\main\java\com\company\project\sub-directory A
        \----src\main\java\com\company\project\sub-directory B
         .....
         \----src\main\java\com\company\project\sub-directory common (common code extracted, will be a spring boot project)
```

Similarly for service B.
Now I have tried a few approaches so far and have not found a solution yet. The most promising thing that I thought was this:

1. Separate the common code into a new repository.
2. Make each of the services into a `pom` packaging instead of currently jar
3. Add the common code as a git submodule where ever I want in the project as a sub-directory and also 
   include it in `pom.xml` of each of the services as

```
<modules>
    <module>path-to-sub-module</module>
</modules>
```

Also, the common project will not have any specific parent like service A or service B. It will be a simple spring boot project with the parent as  `spring-boot-starter-parent`.
So I tried that and after doing the above, when I have the common project as a sub directory, there are lots of compilation errors because the package structure for the common project has now changed. If each of the models was in a package say:

```
package com.project.poc.models;
```

are now throwing error saying this isn't the correct package and rightly so, which should be

```
package com.project.poc.common.src.main.java.com.project.poc.models;
```

Anything I can do about this? or is there something else, something better you guys can suggest I can do to achieve my requirement?

Thanks

Comment: Do you always build all your microservices? Or do you also build single microservices without building the remaining ones? Because if you change the `common` code, you implicitly change all the microsevices.

Comment: @JFMeier Yes, we build the one we are working on without building others. And yes if we change the common code, we implicitly change all of them and that is what is required.

Comment: The usual solution for this kind of problem is to put `common` into a separate project and reference it as a dependency in the microservices. This does not offer you build to "both at once" (at least not without a tool like Jenkins).

Comment: @JF Meier Yes. When I started to research about this, what you are saying was the most suggested solution that I found. But it isn't what I want to do until I have exhausted all the options.

Comment: Beware though that you might create a brittle system that might fail in unexpected ways.